# How to have two domains for same site, but site working in directory in second domain?

Tags: 7

Example:

`www.domain1.com -> Drupal site` in root dir (Managed by Apache)

`www.domain2.com/usa -> Drupal site of domain1.com` (Managed by Nginx)

The idea is that `www.domain2.com/<countrycode>` points to the real domain but in a transparent way (User must not see the existence of the real domain).

What I did:

1) Configured nginx as reverse proxy:

```
## HTTP server.                                                          
server {                                                                 
    listen 80; # IPv4                                                    

    server_name emed.com, www.emed.com;                                  

    access_log /var/log/nginx/drupal.log;                                
    error_log /var/log/nginx/drupal.log;                                 

    keepalive_timeout 75 75;                                             

    root /opt/www/web/drupal;                                            
    index index.php;                                                     

    include apps/drupal/drupal.conf;                                     

    location /fr/ {                                                      
        proxy_set_header Host $host;                                     
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/fr/;                            
        proxy_redirect http://localhost:8080/fr/ http://www.emed.com/fr/;
    }                                                                    

}
```

2) Configured Apache

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
        Alias "/fr" "/var/www/html/drupal7"
</VirtualHost>
```

The problem is that Apache *must* have the `Alias fr` directive, otherwise Drupal generates incorrect URLs:

`www.domain2.com/usa` tries to load assets from `www.domain2.com/sites/...` instead of `www.domain2.com/usa/sites/...`

Is this even possible withouth using Alias? Because the first domain serves on `/` (root)

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to check this module  https://www.drupal.org/project/domain
it has the solution for this